# Form fixed to bottom while content also is fluid

Tags: html, css

I need the bottom half (form) to be fixed to the bottom while the portion above it be fluid. (Chat area)

I managed to get the form fixed to the bottom but the chat area portion is going behind it when I need it to stop where the form begins.

**CSS**

```
.page{
 min-height: 100%
}
#chatBox{
 overflow:scroll;
 position: absolute;
}
.formTextareaWrap{
 padding-left:10px;
 padding-right:10px;
}
#formArea{
 clear: both;
 margin-top: -160px;
 height:160px;
 background-color:#fff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
        <!-- Page Content-->
        <div class="content pageHome page">
            <div id="chatBox">
                <em class="speach-left-title">John Doe says:</em>
                <p class="speach-left">This is just an awesome bubble! It's quite cute isn't it?</p>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <em class="speach-right-title">Jane Doe replied:</em>
                <p class="speach-right blue-bubble">Yeap! It's awesome isn't it and it's not that hard to use! And they act like bubbles, only expanding to 75% of width!</p>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <em class="speach-left-title">John Doe says:</em>
                <p class="speach-left">Awesome stuff!</p>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <em class="speach-right-title">Jane Doe replied:</em>
                <p class="speach-right blue-bubble">Yeap! It's awesome isn't it and it's not that hard to use! And they act like bubbles, only expanding to 75% of width!</p>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="formArea">
            <form action="php/contact.php" method="post" class="contactForm" id="contactForm">
                <fieldset>

                    <div class="formTextareaWrap">
                        <label class="field-title contactMessageTextarea" for="contactMessageTextarea">Message: <span>(required)</span></label>
                        <textarea name="contactMessageTextarea" class="contactTextarea requiredField" id="contactMessageTextarea"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="formSubmitButtonErrorsWrap" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">
                        <input type="submit" class="buttonWrap button button-green contactSubmitButton" id="contactSubmitButton" value="SUBMIT" data-formId="contactForm"/>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: where is the CSS code?

Comment: Couldn't help without CSS

Comment: The CSS is inline styles. Check the DIVs. I can separate it if it's easier to read.

Comment: OK @Aziz I separated it.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve... can you provide a screenshot or an example of it? see my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/azizn/2dpnxgtr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just adding 160px padding to the bottom of `#chatBox`. This made it so the text didnt go under the form when it wasn't supposed to.